# Mathematical Issue in a Formula, Looking for direct mathematical function

Tags: math, plot, formula, calculation

With x, p and s known, I'm trying to solve this problem in R: Find N such as qnorm(p, N, s)=q

Example: Find N such as `30==qnorm(0.05, N, 3)`

My solution:

```r
x<-seq(30, 50, 0.1)
y<-qnorm(0.05, x, 3)
plot(x,y)
```

Looking at the plot, the solution is around 35.
I can refine the answer following this trial method.

My question is: **Is there a direct function to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 2):

The key here is realising that the `qnorm(0.05, N, 3)` is the same as `qnorm(0.05, 0, 3) + N`, since all the `mean` parameter does is to shift the whole distribution left or right. So if we take `30 = qnorm(0.05, N, 3)` and rearrange it, we get:

```r
N <- 30 - qnorm(0.05, 0, 3)

N
#> [1] 34.93456
```

Or to generalise:

```r
inv.qnorm <- function(goal, sd, p) goal - qnorm(p, 0, sd)
```

This gives us an answer with greater precision, speed and memory usage than could be achieved using the sequences-lookup approach.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I create a means vector centred on the goal with length `2*standard_deviation*qnorm(1-p/2)` and then get the element of this vector which has the minimal distance from the goal and return it

```r
inv.qnorm <- function(goal, sd, p, precision=.0001){
  x <- seq(goal - sd* qnorm(1-p/2), goal + sd* qnorm(1-p/2), precision)
  x[which.min(abs(qnorm(p, x, sd)-goal))]
}
inv.qnorm(30, 3, .05)
#> [1] 34.93461
```

[image]